# How to create multiple buttons from existing strings in .txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, button, browser

I wonder how I can create buttons in my `Toolbar` by reading lines from a .txt file.
For example:

```
//bookmarks.txt

http://example.com
http://example2.com
http://example3.com
...
```

What I want is that my program on start should create a button for each line in my .txt with this event:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //fire bookmark event
{
    string text = e.Source.ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.Button: ", "");  
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(text);

}
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I read the .txt:

```
for (int i = 0; i < File.ReadLines(@"bookmarks.txt").Count(); i++)
{
      //Add button right here
}
```

Comment: You are asking how to read a text file and your sample code is an event handler for a button. Please provide the code which reads the file.

Comment: Yes, I want the created buttons to use that eventhandler. I updated with the code that read the file.

Comment: @MarioStoilov Updated one more time with my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use WPF as if it were WinForms. This is how you would fulfil your requirements in WPF... first create a `DependencyProperty` collection in your `Window` code behind and populate it with your text entries:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(YourWindowOrUserControl));

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

...

Items = new ObservableCollection<string>(File.ReadLines(@"bookmarks.txt"));
```

Then you simply data bind the collection to the `ToolBar.ItemsSource` property and declare a `DataTemplate` to define what each `string` should look like... in your case, we'll set it as the text in a `Button`:

```
<ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Margin="1,0,0,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
</ToolBar>
```

Of course, you'll need to set the `Window.DataContext` to the class with your properties... the simplest way is to set it in the code behind constructor like this:

```
public YourWindowOrUserControl
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

You *must* read up about how to set the `DataContext` properly though, as setting it this way is easy, but not necessarily correct.

Finally, you could create a class with all the necessary properties for the `Button`... for example, you could add a property named `Text` and another called `Command` and then make your `Items` property a collection of those. Then you could data bind to it like this:

```
<ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}" Margin="1,0,0,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
</ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create buttons dynamic and add click event on fly:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Location = new Point(yourX, yourY);
btn.Font = new Font(btn.Font.Name, 10);
btn.Text = "Text from your txt file here";
btn.ForeColor = Color.SeaShell; // choose color
btn.AutoSize = true;
btn.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    string text = btn.Text.Replace("System.Windows.Controls.Button: ", "");  
                    WebBrowser1.Navigate(text);
                };
```

(Insert this code in your For. Btw, you can replace the for with while. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) link)